# Weld jsf2 ear skeleton project eclipse

Tags: jsf-2

Anyone knows how to create a skeleton weld ear project (with js2 support) project for eclipse?

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven, try the weld maven archetypes:
http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WeldQuickstartForMavenUsers

Specifically the weld-jsf-jee archetype.

If you use maven or m2eclipse, there are guis for creating new projects with archetypes.  Simply follow: New -> Project -> Maven Project, then select the archetype you would like.  Filter on the word "weld" if you can't find it in the list.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read your question and saw the "EAR" specification.  You could go a long way prototyping with a JEE 6 WAR project though, since it supports EJBs.  Refactor into separate modules when you have a non EJB-lite requirement.